# Minizinc - assign job to specific machine

Tags: minizinc

I have say n jobs and m machines and have a jobtype array with type of job. If the job is of specific type in job type array , i have to assign even numbered machine among the available else to the odd numbered machine. Is it possible with minizinc?
Snippet I tried given below:

```
forall(w in 1..num_workers) (
    if jobtype[job] == "NC" then assignment[job,(w mod 2 ==0)]=1
     else assignment[job,(w mod 2 !=0)]=1 endif
)
```

which is giving the following warning

```
WARNING: undefined result becomes false in Boolean context
(array access out of bounds)
```

TIA

Comment: Can you show the complete code with some small data instance? Note that `w mod 2` is either 0 or 1, and `w mod 2 == 0` is true or false. Probably neither of them are good values of indices in the `assignment` matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one model that might be what you want, i.e. to assign even numbered machines to the jobs marked as "NC". The important constraint is the following, which might be the one you want. Here we use a temporary decision variable `w` in the range of `1..num_workers`, and then ensure that for the NC jobs the machine number must be even:

```
forall(job in 1..num_jobs) (
    let { var 1..num_workers: w; } in
    % Jobs with NC must be assigned to even numbered workers (machines)
   if jobtype[job] == "NC" then w mod 2 == 0 else w mod 2 == 1 endif
   /\ assignment[job,w]=1
)
```

Here is the full model - as I imagined it - with 7 jobs and 7 workers. I assume that a worker/machine can only be assigned to at most one job. Well, it's a lot of guesswork...

```
int: num_workers = 7;
int: num_jobs = 7;
array[1..num_jobs] of string: jobtype = ["NC","X","NC","X","X","NC","X"];
% decision variables
array[1..num_jobs, 1..num_workers] of var 0..1: assignment;
solve satisfy;
constraint
   forall(job in 1..num_jobs) (
     let { var 1..num_workers: w; } in
     % Jobs with NC must be assigned to even numbered workers (machines)
     if jobtype[job] == "NC" then w mod 2 == 0 else w mod 2 == 1 endif
     /\
     assignment[job,w]=1
   )
  /\ % at most one worker for each job (or perhaps not)
  forall(job in 1..num_jobs) (
     sum([assignment[job,worker] | worker in 1..num_workers]) <= 1 
  )
  /\ % and at most one job per worker (or perhaps not)
  forall(worker in 1..num_workers) (
    sum([assignment[job,worker] | job in 1..num_jobs]) <= 1
  )
;

output [
  if w == 1 then "\n" else " " endif ++
    show(assignment[j,w]) 
  ++ if w == num_workers then " (\(jobtype[j]))" else "" endif
  | j in 1..num_jobs, w in 1..num_workers
];
```

The model yields 144 different solutions. Here's the first:

```
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ("NC")
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ("X")
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ("NC")
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ("X")
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ("X")
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ("NC")
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ("X")
```

Comment: Thanks hakank.. Your guesswork is correct except that my code also has certain capacity constraints for each worker... could not work out assignment of job to even numbered worker .. It is solved now.. Thanks a lot

Comment: One doubt how could i add a duration for a job in this assignment problem? Duration varies for an even numbered and odd numbered machine.

Comment: Well, adding duration to each job makes it a different problem: rather a scheduling problem than a assignment problem but it depends on how you want to use the duration. The traditional way is to use cumulative for the scheduling. Though you might then consider a different representation of the assignments, not as a 0/1-matrix but as a list for each worker which jobs they are assigned to.

Comment: In my case im unable to use cumulative for scheduling since i know only the duration for each worker not the duration of each job in a worker. Since the duration of each job is decided based on the assignment to even numbered or odd numbered machine. (As i told earlier even and odd machines have different durations )

Comment: If you want some help with this, please create a new question with as much info as possible, including as small as possible dataset.